# Azure AppendBlob number of block/writes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using `AppendBlob` in Azure for logging. After some time I experienced `409 Conflict Error`. My guess is the maximal amount of block/writes (50.000) was reached.

Is there any way to get count of blocks/writes in the blob?

Comment: Check the http status message (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage), it contains a detailed error message.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it says `The block count exceeds the maximum permissible limit.` Is there any method to find out block count in blob with C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Azure Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx), you can find the table of [Blob Service Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179439.aspx) which list the error codes may be returned by an operation against the Blob service includes `Conflict 409`, please see below.

[image]

The details for the maximums of `AppendBlob`, you can refer to the section `About Append Blobs` of the reference page [`Understanding Block Blobs, Append Blobs, and Page Blobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691964.aspx) as below.

> Each block in an append blob can be a different size, up to a maximum of 4 MB, and an append blob can include up to 50,000 blocks. The maximum size of an append blob is therefore slightly more than 195 GB (4 MB X 50,000 blocks).

As @yonisha said, if using REST API [`Append Block`](http://Append%20Block), you can get the block count for `AppendBlob` via get the response header `x-ms-blob-committed-block-count` which is the number of committed blocks present in the blob and can be used to control how many more appends can be done.

For C#, getting the block count via the property `AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount` form the `BlobProperties` for the object `CloudAppendBlob`, please see the reference [BlobProperties.AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.appendblobcommittedblockcount.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For C# you can simply issue appendBlob.Properties.AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount.

Wissam

Comment: This is old, but I just ran into the same issue. What Wissam is saying is to use something like var blockCount = appendBlob.Properties.AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount;  then if the block count is going to excceed 50k get a new blob.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [Operations on Append blob documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt427364.aspx), the only **specific** available operation on **Append blob type** is the *'Append Block'* operation.

Nevertheless, you can get the **committed block count** from the [x-ms-blob-committed-block-count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt427365.aspx) **response header** of the Append Block operation. From the documentation:

> The number of committed blocks present in the blob. This can be used
>   to control how many more appends can be done.